# AWS ELB Apache Get Client IP, Avoid X-Forwarded-For Spoofing

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, apache2, amazon-elb, x-forwarded-for

From apache docs (https://httpd.apace.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html) we implemented the following assignment on our server:

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
```

to get a client's IP rather than the ELB's IP. However, we didn't notice that the ELB also appends all other `X-Forwarded-For` values to the left of that string. So this is not a secure way to get a client's IP.

We've used `LogFormat` with `\"%{X-Forwarded-For}i\"` to verify the values being passed in are as documented.

```
192.168.0.0, 10.0.0.0
```

is what would come through if `192.168.0.0` were the header being passed and `10.0.0.0` were the client's requesting machine. A standard request without the header would be:

```
10.0.0.0
```

Is there a way to extract the rightmost IP? I was thinking something like,

```
RemoteIPHeader ('(?:\d{1,3}[.]){3}\d{1,3}$', X-Forwarded-For,)[0]
```

but can't find a function in apache to configure this. I could do this in PHP but then my logs will all have the wrong IPs logged.

I've tried:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For '((?:\d{1,3}[.]){3}\d{1,3})$' ip_is=$1
RemoteIPHeader %{ip_is}
```

but this didn't take affect.

**Update:**

Apache configuration runs with:

```
LogFormat "%{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}t %a %u %A %p %m %U %q %>s \"%{User-agent}i\" %T/%D \"%{X-Forwarded-For}i\"" w3c_extended
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.com/access.log w3c_extended
```

I currently receive either:

```
2021-02-27 14:29:06 10.0.21.150 - 10.0.20.222 443 GET /IPtest.php ?v=1 200 "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" 0/2822 "73.149.97.219"
```

or

```
2021-02-27 14:29:06 10.0.21.150 - 10.0.20.222 443 GET /IPtest.php ?v=1 200 "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" 0/2822 "10.0.21.150, 73.149.97.219"
```

I need to capture `73.149.97.219` in both scenarios.

Comment: When you use remoteIP you don't have to use %{X-Forwarded-For}i, but %a, what is the output of that?

Comment: @on8tom Isn't `%a` the remoteaddr address? That comes through as the ELB's address, `10.x.x.x.`

Comment: Just to be clear, if the client has the ip address 1.2.3.4, but adds his own header "x-forwarded-for: 192.2.0.1", then the ELB changes the x-forwarded for header to "x-forwarded-for: 192.2.0.1, 1.2.3.4" and you are only interested in the 1.2.3.4 address?

Comment: @on8tom Correct

Comment: well in't %a not exactly what what you want?

Comment: @on8tom The ELB makes `%a` its address not the clients.

Comment: I've posted an aswer with the trusted proxy directive that you probably are missign

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229293/discussion-between-on8tom-and-user3783243).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm testing with apache 2.4 and remoteIP

```
RemoteIPHeader x-forwarded-for
```

You'll also need to tell your apache what the internal IP address of your Load balancer (Reverse Proxy) is. There is no reliable easy way to determine that internal IP and it can by 'any' RFC1918 (private) IP address
So you'll need to add those 3 subnets.

```
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 10.0.0.0/8
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 172.16.0.0/12
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 192.168.0.0/16
```

and then use %a for the logFormat

```
LogFromat %a
```

i've tested with

```
RemoteIPTrustedProxy 127.0.0.1
LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

tested with curl

```
curl 127.0.0.1/so 
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Feb/2021:15:02:38 +0100] "GET /so/ HTTP/1.1" 200 167 "-" "curl/7.52.1"

curl 127.0.0.1/so/ -H "x-forwarded-for:  1.2.3.4"
1.2.3.4 - - [27/Feb/2021:15:04:06 +0100] "GET /so/ HTTP/1.1" 200 167 "-" "curl/7.52.1"

curl 127.0.0.1/so/ -H "x-forwarded-for:  8.5.4.1, 1.2.3.4"
1.2.3.4 - - [27/Feb/2021:15:04:31 +0100] "GET /so/ HTTP/1.1" 200 167 "-" "curl/7.52.1"
```

Comment: `RemoteIPHeader x-forwarded-for` came through with my WAN as expected. `RemoteIPTrustedProxy` came through with a LAN address, `RemoteIPInternalProxy` came through with a different LAN address. I haven't tested the forward header yet because the standard request still needs to map through. ( I use `LAN` and `private ip` interchangeably)

Comment: I'm not shure how to interpret your last comment. but you can also add RemoteIPInternalProxy 10.0.0.0/8 to trust all private ip addresses in the 10/8 subnet

Comment: I've added a short update, is that clearer? If this answer suffices for that could you put a synopsis in, e.g. `RemoteIPHeader x-forwarded-for\nRemoteIPTrustedProxy ....` or whichever order they should go in. Perhaps I have them incorrect and one overwrites the other

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem in different context - apache was resolving hostnames from manipulated `X-Forwarded-For` header. E.g. `X-Forwarded-For: mumblemuble.burpcollaborator.com, 1.1.1.1, anotherdomainapachewillresolve.com`

My solution was to modify the `X-Forwarded-For` header to only include the IP address added by ELB, and discard IP addresses which ELB appended to the header.

Instead of other reverse proxies, ELB appends existing `X-Forwarded-For` addresses and hostname *before* the client IP. For other reverse proxies you should modify regexp to discard everything after first comma.

```
# because of "early", headers can only be set in a main server or virtual host context. 
RequestHeader edit  "X-Forwarded-For" "^(.+),(.+)$" "$2" early
```